# Check if a particular string ends with some text

Tags: regex, mongodb

i am trying to use **regex** in my mongo query and i want to make a search based on a condition that mongo should return me all the results whose `name` key ends with a particular text.

For example:- Input text `mob`, then all my results should have their `name` key ending with `mob`.

So far i have tried this

```
Collection.find({name: new RegExp("$'"+titleStr, 'i')}).exec()
```

But i am getting no results.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb has `regex` operator keyword for searching using regular expression.Try this

```
Collection.find( { name: { $regex: /titleStr$/, $options: 'i' } } ).exec()
```

Comment: actually your answer is partially correct, for my need, the expression should look like `Collection.find( { name: { $regex: /titleStr$/, $options: 'i' } } ).exec()`

Anyways thanx

Comment: I am just giving you an idea to use `regex` in your query

Comment: Thanx buddy! Actually i am accustomed to this, i only needed a correct expression

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result when i replaced regex part of the code with

```
Collection.find({name: new RegExp(titleStr + '$', 'i')}).exec()
```

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB has a `$regex` operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Things should be simple from there I guess